# Gson can not cast "Object"class in my object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using **Gson** to cast my class to Json, I have a field called **payload**
which must to be my class itself.

My class is as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Object payload;
}
```

But when I use it as follow:

```
MyClass myClassObj = MyClass()
myClassObj.setId(1L);
myClassObj.setName("Example");
myClassObj.setPayload(myClassObj);
```

And I see the result of:

```
String result = new Gson().toJson(myClassObj);
```

The result does not contain payload data object.

```
{"id":1, "name":"Example"}
```

I need something like:

```
{"id":1, "name":"Example", "payload": {"id":1, "name":"Example"}}
```

Thanks in advance.
Any help will be useful.

Comment: The whole point of `Object` is that it can be anything.  How are you expecting Gson to know what to do with it?

Comment: @azurefrog thanks, you are right, I post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change it to be defined as such

```
public class MyClass {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private MyClass payload = null;
}
```

Gson serialized parameters that are not transient. Object does not have the "id" and "name" parameters you are wanting to serialize. MyClass does. Ensure that payload's default value is null otherwise you may have an infinite loop on your hands when serializing to json.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, **Object** can be anything, so before to set **payload** of my class I made the follow:

```
myClassObj.setPayload(new Gson.fromJson(myClassObj.toString(), myClassObj.class);
```

**Note:**

In MyClass I have override toString method as follow:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
```

If someone has a better solution, feel free to post it.